# Install ZeroMQ with enable-drafts using conda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, zeromq

I installed [pyzmq](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyzmq) with conda and libzmq5-dev (using apt).
When I use zmq.SERVER (also tried zmq.DISH, zmq.RADIO):

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SERVER)
```

get error:

> socket = context.socket(zmq.SERVER)
> AttributeError: module 'zmq' has no attribute 'SERVER'

I know this is an error due to a disabled draft, but I don't know how to install pyzmq using conda with enable-draft , because all tutorials say use pip install pyzmq --install-option=--enable-drafts (like [this](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/draft/install.sh))

Or maybe I can enable pyzmq draft in Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither [the Anaconda](https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/pyzmq-feedstock/blob/e32b79a58e81a1c1c6eb8ef49a475a19de9ebf07/recipe/build.sh) nor [the Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/pyzmq-feedstock/blob/69ca7c91bb2265d9423a649213efbc9762cdf427/recipe/build.sh) builds include that flag during build. Simplest solution would be just to use pip. [For stability reasons](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env), I wouldn't do this in the **base** environment. Instead, create a new environment with Python and pip installed (plus whatever else you expect to need), activate the environment, then run that `pip` command from within the environment.

More long term, if you have a solid argument for the flag being included by default, then you could try posting an Issue or creating a Pull Request on one or both of the feedstocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
# conda install r-rzmq
# python

>> import zmq
>>
```

It worked